# In the Array.prototype.find's implementation, why do we need to use Objetct(this) to convert to an object?

Tags: javascript

In the [`Array.prototype.find`'s implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#polyfill), why do we need to use `Object(this)` to convert `this` to an object?

```
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    value: function(predicate) {
      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }

      // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      // 5. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;

      // 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 7. Return undefined.
      return undefined;
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });
}
```

Comment: The difference could be observed with `Array.prototype.find.call("test", console.log)`, without that line it would be a string primitive, and with that line it is a String object (as the specification says).

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, because the specification says so.

Why does it do that though? Because later on, it accesses properties (like `.length` and `[k]`) of the value, which must be an object for that. Sure, the member access syntax used in the polyfill would already would do this for us, but in the spec text the *Get* algorithm requires an object and the conversion to an object should happen only once, not on each member access (although it would be indistinguishable).

Why do we *want* to convert arbitrary values to objects? Because a method can be called with a primitive value as is `this` argument as well - unusual but possible. And as the spec says

> Note: The `find` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an `Array` object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

An example:

```
String.prototype.find = Array.prototype.find;
console.log("test".find(x => x > 'f' && x < 't'))
```